# How to assign a "Boltzmann weight"?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, statistical-thermodynamics, thermodynamics

I would like to assign a "Boltzmann weight" i.e. $\exp(-E/kT)$ to interactions between particles based on the relative energies. But wouldn't the largest particle-particle energies have the smallest weighting? Shouldn't it be the opposite? I'm hoping someone can explain this to me.

Comment: ideal interactions are usually a negative energy, so the exponential of a negative times a negative, is a big weight. If they are too close, the energy will be positive, and the exponential of a large negative number is a small weight

Comment: I don't see the issue with large energies having the lower weights. Isn't that the whole idea? Nature usually favors lower energies.

Comment: @Szgoger well, nature favors the lowest free energy. Potential energy is usually similar.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is your instinct is correct, a large energy will have a small weight.

As a simple case, lets look at the energy of interaction between two Lennard-Jones particles

[image]

At the most favorable distance, $r/\sigma = r_m$, the energy of interaction is the most negative it can be, which is the equilibrium point. The Boltzmann weight at this distance would also be the largest possible out of any interactions.

On the other hand, at $r/\sigma=1$, the particles begin overlapping and the energy gets positive(repulsive), very fast. The Boltzmann weight would be very small, becoming vanishingly small the more the particles overlap.

Using the dimensions in the image, the largest Boltzmann factor is at $r/\sigma = r_m$ which is

$E=-1 \rightarrow \exp(-[-1]) = 2.718$,

meanwhile, on the other hand, positive values are quite small i.e. for $r/\sigma < 1$

$E=1 \rightarrow \exp(-[1]) = 0.368$.

$E=3 \rightarrow \exp(-[3]) = 0.05$.

We expect overlapping particles to have a smaller weight since energy of interaction becomes repulsive. The most favorable interaction is at $r/\sigma = r_m$

In reality, however, it is the free energy, not the potential energy, that determines where equilibrium is.